# htaccess stuck in endless loop

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

Ive put an htaccess file on a site with the following

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.ic-furniture\.com)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://ic-furniture.com/$1 [R=301,L]
order deny,allow

redirect 301    /index.php  http://ic-furniture.com/
redirect 301    /index.html http://ic-furniture.com/

ErrorDocument 404 http://ic-furniture.com/404.html
```

What im trying to do is

- remove the www.
- remove /index.html
- if some one clicks a link to site/index.php i want them to go to the home page
- 404 error page to 404.html

but when i upload this im getting an error

> **The page isn't redirecting properly**
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

any idea what im doing wrong here, ive been going crazy trying to figure it out

Comment: ive had a look arround and the problem is caused by - Technically, when you request / you request index.html (given index.html is the DirectoryIndex, which is usually the case) so that will indeed result in a loop - so instead you have to use - RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.mysite.com/ [L,R=301]

Comment: Yeah.. Your right! I was answering when I saw your comment. Actually, here in **OP**, it's allowable to answer your own question.

Comment: ahh ok ill write it bellow, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable to check if the actual request is for the index file, then redirect accordingly:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(php|html)
RewriteRule ^ http://ic-furniture.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: is this preferable, when would there be a time when you go to index.html and not want index.html ?

Comment: @sam this is preferable over the two `redirect` statements that you have. It does the same thing except won't cause a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ive had a look arround and the problem is caused by :

> Technically, when you request / you request index.html (given
>   index.html is the DirectoryIndex, which is usually the case) so that
>   will indeed result in a loop

so instead you have to use :

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ mysite.com [L,R=301]
```